# Skitch failed to work for Big Sur even though I have granted Screen Recording

Tags: permission, big-sur, screen-capture

I have granted Skitch Screen Recording permission but Skitch still failed to capture the screen.

[image: screen recording permission]

This happened after I upgraded to the latest Big Sur patch. It used to work.

How do I fix it? Thanks!

[image: skitch]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Big Sur, it is the Skitch Helper which needs to be granted the Screen Recording permission.

[image]

To fix this, I suggest completely uninstalling Skitch and reinstall. Either when installing or on first run, you will be asked to grant the Screen Recording permission. Make sure you are using the current version 2.9 Skitch.

Comment: Oh I found after checked Skitch Helper it works!. But what is Skitch Helper ?

Comment: Screen Recording requires a process running with privileges which should not be available to a desktop app which has lots of code which doesn't require privileges and might have vulnerabilities. So best practice is to put the carefully debugged privileged code in a 'helper' app which can do things with privileges and communicates results back to desktop app.  A developer could tell us, but it may be a requirement for an app in the Apple App Store which requires privileges.

Answer (score 1):

I initially installed Skitch via Homebrew Cask, but until today have had ongoing issues where Skitch kept loosing permission despite, going in and disabling then enabling again and having it work for a short period of time.

Today ran `brew cask uninstall skitch` and instead now downloaded it from Mac AppStore. This seems to have addressed the permissions issues I was having.

Added for anyone else arriving here with this same issue.